# Question About The Remark after Proposition 1.4.11 from Measure Theory by Donold Cohn

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

### My Question

> Define subsets $G$, $G_0$, and $G_1$ of $\mathbb{R}$ by
> \begin{align*}
>     G &= \{x:x=r+n\sqrt{2}\ \text{for some $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$}\},\\
>     G_0 &= \{x:x=r+2n\sqrt{2}\ \text{for some $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$}\},\ \text{and}\\
>     G_1 &= \{x:x=r+(2n+1)\sqrt{2}\ \text{for some $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$}\}.
> \end{align*}
> Define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by letting $x \sim y$ hold when $x-y\in G$; the relation $\sim$ is then an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$. Use the axiom of choice to form a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains exactly one representative of each equivalence class of $\sim$. Let $A = E + G_0$ (that is, let $A$ consist of the points that have the form $e+g_0$ for some $e$ in $E$ and some $g_0$ in $G_0$).

I got confused by the book's remark that "the set $A$ defined above is not Lebesgue measurable: if it were, then both $A$ and $A^c$ would include (in fact, would be) Lebesgue measurable sets of positive Lebesgue measure". Could someone please help me explain why this is true?

### Background Information

The above remark is made after the follow proposition:

> **Proposition 1.4.11**$\quad$ *There is a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that each Lebesgue measurable set that is included in $A$ or in $A^c$ has Lebesgue measure zero.*
>
> **Proof**$\quad$ Define subsets $G$, $G_0$, and $G_1$ of $\mathbb{R}$ by
> \begin{align*}
>     G &= \{x:x=r+n\sqrt{2}\ \text{for some $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$}\},\\
>     G_0 &= \{x:x=r+2n\sqrt{2}\ \text{for some $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$}\},\ \text{and}\\
>     G_1 &= \{x:x=r+(2n+1)\sqrt{2}\ \text{for some $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$}\}.
> \end{align*}
> One can prove that $G$ and $G_0$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ (under addition), and $G_0$ and $G_1$ are disjoint, that $G_1 = G_0 + \sqrt{2}$, and that $G = G_0 \bigcup G_1$. Define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by letting $x \sim y$ hold when $x-y\in G$; the relation $\sim$ is then an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$. Use the axiom of choice to form a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains exactly one representative of each equivalence class of $\sim$. Let $A = E + G_0$ (that is, let $A$ consist of the points that have the form $e+g_0$ for some $e$ in $E$ and some $g_0$ in $G_0$).
>
> We now show that there does note exist a Lebesgue measurable subset $B$ of $A$ such that $\lambda(B)>0$. For this let us assume that such a set exists; we will derive a contradiction. Proposition 1.4.10 implies that there is an interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ that is included in $\text{diff}(B)$ and hence in $\text{diff}(A)$. Since $G_1$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it meets the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and hence meets $\text{diff}(A)$. This, however, is impossible, since each element of $\text{diff}(A)$ is of the form $e_1-e_2+g_0$ (where $e_1$ and $e_2$ belong to $E$ and $g_0$ belongs to $G_0$) and so cannot belong to $G_1$ (the relation $e_1-e_2+g_0=g_1$ would imply that $e_1=e_2$ and $g_0=g_1$, contradicting the disjointness of $G_0$ and $G_1$). This completes our proof that every Lebesgue measurable subset of $A$ must have Lebesgue measure zero.
>
> One can check that $A^c = E + G_1$ and hence that $A^c = A + \sqrt{2}$. It follows that each Lebesgue measurable subset of $A^c$ is of the form $B+\sqrt{2}$ for some Lebesgue measurable subset $B$ of $A$. Since $A$ has no Lebesgue measurable subsets of positive measure, it follows that $A^c$ also has no such subsets, and with this the proof is complete.

The definition of $\text{diff}$ is the following:

> **Definition**$\quad$ Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\text{diff}(A)$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
> \begin{align*}
> \text{diff}(A) = \{x-y:x \in A\ \text{and}\ y \in A\}.
> \end{align*}

Proposition 1.4.10 is the following:

> **Proposition 1.4.10**$\quad$ *Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(A) > 0$. Then $\text{diff}(A)$ includes an open interval that contains 0.*

---

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ were measurable then so would $A+\sqrt2=A^c$ be, and both would have the same measure (since the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is invariant by translation).

- By Proposition 1.4.11, we would then have $\lambda(A)=\lambda(A^c)=0$. But this is impossible, since $\infty=\lambda(\Bbb R)=\lambda(A)+\lambda(A^c)$.
- Equivalently, but closer to Cohn's formulation: we would then have $\infty=\lambda(\Bbb R)=\lambda(A)+\lambda(A^c)=2\lambda(A)=2\lambda(A^c)$ hence $\lambda(A)=\lambda(A^c)=\infty>0$, but this is impossible by Proposition 1.4.11.